# How to analyze HTTP Post response faster

Tags: http, delphi, idhttp, delphi-10.1-berlin

I have written a simple program that checks data periodically. The problem is that the checking process slows down over time. First it sends 2 posts in one second, after like 45s it sends one post, eventually it stops completely. I do not know what is wrong here.

```
procedure TForm2.CheckURLs;
var
  lHTTP: TIdHTTP;
  IdSSL : TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL;
  N: Integer;
  Access: string;
  Params, Reply: TStringList;
  Cookie: TIdCookie;
begin
  lHTTP := TIdHTTP.Create(nil);
  try
    IdSSL := TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create(lHTTP);
    IdSSL.SSLOptions.Method := sslvTLSv1;
    IdSSL.SSLOptions.Mode := sslmClient;
    lHTTP.IOHandler := IdSSL;
    lHTTP.ReadTimeout := 30000;
    lHTTP.HandleRedirects := True;
    lHTTP.Request.UserAgent := 'Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; Nexus 5 Build/MRA58N) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/46.0.2490.76 Mobile Safari/537.36';
    lHTTP.Get('https://www.mywebserver.com', TStream(nil));
    Cookie := lHTTP.CookieManager.CookieCollection.Cookie['id', 'www.mywebserver.com'];
    if Cookie <> nil then
      Access := Cookie.Value;
  finally
  end;

  Params := TStringList.Create;
  Reply  := TStringList.Create;

  TTask.Create(
    procedure
    var
      N, m, i : integer;
    begin
      Params.Add('IDs=' +B.Strings[i]);
      try
        lHTTP.Request.CustomHeaders.Values['id'] := Access;
        lHTTP.Request.CustomHeaders.Values['X-Requested-With'] := 'XMLHttpRequest';
        lHTTP.Request.Referer := 'https://www.mywebserver.com/';
        lHTTP.Request.ContentType := 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded';
        lHTTP.Request.UserAgent := 'Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; Nexus 5 Build/MRA58N) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/46.0.2490.76 Mobile Safari/537.36';
        lHTTP.ConnectTimeout := 0;
        Reply.Text := lHTTP.Post('https://www.mywebserver.com/', Params);

        if AnsiContainsStr(Reply.Text, 'nothing') then
        begin
          TThread.Synchronize(nil,
            procedure
            begin
              Memo1.Lines.Add(B.Strings[i]);
              Label2.Caption := Memo1.Lines.Count.ToString;
            end
          );
        end;        
      finally
        Reply.Clear;
      end;
    end
  ).Start;
end;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to what technicolor said, `TTask` in Delphi 10.1 Berlin has known timing issues, such as:

[RSP-15233: TTask Stuck and take a very very long time to start](https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-15233)

[RSP-12557: TTask serialize parallel tasks without apparent reason](https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-12557)

To avoid these issues, try using `TThread.CreateAnonymousThread()` instead of `TTask`.

Comment: I tested RSP-15233 and sure enough only about 9 Tasks started. After some testing I believe what happens is that a Task is sent to the main thread and the sleep call stops the rest from launching at least for a while.

Adding a SyncObject solved that for me:

  x := 0;
  for i := 1 to 25 do
    TTask.Create(procedure  begin
          OutputDebugString(Pchar('Started::' + TInterlocked.Increment(x).ToString));
          sleep(maxint);
    end).start;

Answer (score 0):

Your slowness may come from these two part of your programm :
Downloading the datas or working on them.

By experience, I suspect the website to slowing you, so you could try to comment out everything (carefully of course) after the download procedure. Running this program again should gave the same result, and then giving us confirmation on the website "fault".

To avoid being blocked for 45 seconds, caused by an anti-robot protection, try to preventively slow down your program by adding some seconds of pause after every request.
Even without protection, it's a good practice to slow down a bit our webbots. We don't do DoS :)